# cellForRowAtIndexPath not being called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am working on a project where I need to populate the cells in a table and have them show on the screen. I've got the table to show but now data is being shown in the cells. I've tried using breakpoints and found that this method never gets called. The method just before it (numberOfRowsInSection) does get called. Any suggestions?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        Resident *aResident = (Resident *)[appDelegate.residents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];   
        cell.textLabel.text = aResident.name;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

        return cell;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the delegate and datasource for the TableView ?

Comment: dint notice that.. my bad.. so it should be that the numberOfRows / numberOfSections returned is 0..

Comment: You were right, the count was returning zero. Now I just have to figure out why the array is coming back with a zero count.             - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSLog(@"Count = %i", [appDelegate.residents count]);
    return [appDelegate.residents count];

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I posted a follow up question of how to return the count [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10337374/return-the-count-of-an-nsmutablearray-from-an-xml-id-number-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, numberOfRowsInSection probably returns 0. Show it and where you populate your data source.